# Web table iteration - Java Selenium

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table, webdriver

I am trying to loop through a calendar web table and if the calendar date is greater than or equal to current date click the radio button the corresponds to it. The rest of the code works but that.

updated code

```
dowhileloop: do {
   // holds dates from 5th column in list
   List < WebElement > payDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//tr[position()>1]/td[position()=5]"));

   // prints out dates from 5th column in list
   List < String > texts = payDates.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
   System.out.println("date ->" + texts);

   //Begin for-loop
    for (WebElement pd: payDates) {
    System.out.println("sample1-> " + pd.getText());

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date payDate = dateFormat.parse(pd.getText());
    System.out.println("sample2-> " + dateFormat.format(payDate));

    if (payDate.after(new Date())) {
     System.out.println("inside for loop");

     String radiobutton = "//TBODY[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody']/TR[7]/TD[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]";
     WebElement calrow = driver.findElement(By.xpath(pd + radiobutton));

     calrow.click();
     Thread.sleep(10000);

     PS_OBJ_CycleData.donebtn(driver).click();
     break dowhileloop;
    }

   } //** END third inner for-loop****
```

---- Requested Radio Button HTML code ----
[image]

```
 < div id = "changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows[5].cells[0]_widget"
tabindex = "0"class = "revitRadioButton dijitRadio dijitRadioChecked"
onfocus = "var registry = require('dijit/registry'); registry.byId('changeStartWeekGrid').changeActiveCell('changeStartWeekGrid_row_5_cell_0', event);"
onblur = "var registry = require('dijit/registry'); registry.byId('changeStartWeekGrid').blurActiveCell('changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows[5]', 'changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows[5].cells[0]');" >
 < div class = "revitRadioButtonIcon" > < /div> < /div>
```

----- Additional radio button HTML code ----
 [image]

```
<span class="dndBar checked" data-tag="dndBar" id="changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows[5].cells[0]_img">
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
```

------------console view ----

[image]

Comment: So for today(16th Mar) need to select the third radio button?

Comment: well yes that is correct however it could be any day

Comment: I posted more html code above

Comment: Try this xpath to get the 'pay date' elements - //tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')]/td[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span]

Comment: This will give you a list of pay date by using the getText() method. Loop it and apply thelogic to get necessary date. Store the index of the loop that satisfies the condition

Comment: This index should also be the row number of the radio button u need to select.

Comment: Could you please give me a visual example. I think your saying use this xpath with the code structure i have above? Also i understand everything up until the part (Loop it and apply the logic to get necessary date. Store the index of the loop that satisfies the condition)

Comment: A visual representation would be helpful.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the pseudo code... Hope it helps

```
List<WebElement> payDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')]/td[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span]"));

int reqIndex = 0;

for(WebElement pd;payDates) {

//Use class java.time.LocalDate to do the parsing andcomparison with current date.
if (condition satisfied) 
     break
else
     reqIndex++;
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_row_'" + reqIndex +"]")/path to radio button).click()
```

Comment: when you say path to radio button is that an xpath? or should it be an xpath or can it be by id?

Comment: It is whatever locator you need to find the appropriate radio button and select it

Comment: thank you for your help so far still working on this this is the xpath to the radio button however i get red lines in eclipe for the 2nd part after the slash(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_row_'" + reqIndex +"]")/TBODY[@id="changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody"]/TR[7]/TD[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]).click();)

Comment: I am not an expert with xpath so i tried some variation and stl have lines

Comment: Try this -- "//tr[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_row_'" + reqIndex +"])/TBODY[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody']/TR[7]/TD[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]"

Comment: I got this error  from stack trace (( org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression  //tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')]/td[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span] because of the following error:
Error: Filter expression must evaluate to nodeset.))

Comment: the only code i am testing right now is this List<WebElement> payDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')]/td[contains(@id,'_cell_5')/span]"));
        System.out.println(payDates);
        Thread.sleep(10000);

Comment: This is the direct xpath for both i am trying to find how to put them together (//*[@id="changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody"]
                                                 //*[@id="changeStartWeekGrid_row_4_cell_4"])

Comment: I tested the xpaths they work however i think the problem is that it is not starting at row 0 its strting here first <tr id="changeStartWeekGrid_row_column_sizes" i need to skip this do you know how i can do that?

Comment: Thanks for your help i found the correct xpath which is driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')and not(starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_column'))]/td[5]/span"));

Comment: @GrasshopperI updated my code however with the list web elements that work but I still am not able to lick the radio button with the selected row.

Comment: @Jonathan Can you update with latest code and add the html inspect by clicking on the radio button...

Comment: I sure will one moment

Comment: @GrasshopperI I have updated my code and given you the radio button HTML inspect element code

Comment: can u try this xpath in the browser console and check if this returns the radio button in the second row.. "//tr[@id='changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows.rows[1].cells[0]_widget']//div[@class='revitRadioButtonIcon']"

Comment: If this works then you will need to just make the '1' variable dynamic in 'rows[1]' to the row index you have from the logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167174/discussion-between-jonathan-and-grasshopper).

Comment: I posted something new that shows the results of the x path query in chrome console view

Comment: Change the tr to div at the start. My mistake.

Comment: I believe this is going to work thanks //div[@id='changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows.rows[1].cells[0]_w‌​idget']//div[@clas‌​‌​‌​s=‌​'revitRadioButtonIco‌​n'] however you said something about making the '1' variable dynamic in 'rows[1]' to the row index.. can you give me a visual example based on my code of what you are saying?

Comment: This will always select the 2nd row. The matching row could be some other row. Something like ....rows["+rowindex+"].... Instead of the current hardcoded one.

Comment: so something like this for the matching row? //div[@id='changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows.rows["+rowindex+"].cells[0]_w‌​idget']//div[@clas‌​‌​‌​s=‌​'revitRadioButtonIco‌​n'] ?

Comment: yeah exactly like this

Answer (score 0):

```
/* The below code doesn't loop through the table. The logic is , The Calendar Webtable starts from Sunday and the First Element that is clickable is the first day of the month. So based on which is the first clickable element and the date to select, the getRowColumnIndex function tells which row and column to select. This way you never traverse through the Webtable and the operation is faster*/
   public static void selectCalendarDate(WebDriver driver, String tableId, int dateToSelect) {
        Map<String,Integer> daysMap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        daysMap.put("SUNDAY", 0);
        daysMap.put("MONDAY", 1);
        daysMap.put("TUESDAY", 2);
        daysMap.put("WEDNESDAY", 3);
        daysMap.put("THURSDAY", 4);
        daysMap.put("FRIDAY", 5);
        daysMap.put("SATURDAY", 6);
        int firstElement = daysMap.get(LocalDate.now().minusDays(LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth()-1).getDayOfWeek().toString());
        int rowColumn[] = getRowColumnIndex(dateToSelect, firstElement);
        rowColumn[0]= rowColumn[0]+2;
        WebElement elementtoClick= driver.findElement(By.xpath(tableId+"/tbody[1]/tr["+rowColumn[0]+"]/td["+rowColumn[1]+"]")); 
        elementtoClick.click();
        }
        public static int[] getRowColumnIndex(int date, int firstElement) {
        int row = 0, column = 0;

        if (firstElement > 0) {
            date = date + firstElement;
            row = (date % 7) > 0 ? (date / 7) + 1 : (date / 7);
            column = ((date % 7) == 0) ? 7 : (date % 7);
        } else {
            row = (date / 7) ;
            column = ((date % 7) == 0) ? 7 : (date % 7);
        }
        int rowcolumn[] = { row, column };
        return (rowcolumn);
    }
```